# Impersonation memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net, winapi, memory-leaks

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=VS.100).aspx there is an example on how to do impersonation with .net 4.0. We have used this example in a class that inherits IDisposable for ease of use. However, when we use this class in a asp.net web application, we notice a slight but steady increase of Pool Paged Bytes in performance monitor. After a week, the application crashes.

I've tried different implementations of the impersonation-class, using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=VS.90).aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158 as reference, but they all show the same leak.

Where does this leak come from? Is there a problem with the windows api? We are running Windows 2008 R2.

This is our current version of the impersonation class:

```
public class Impersonator : IDisposable
{
    public Impersonator(string username, string domain, string password)
    {
        if (!ImpersonateValidUser(username, domain, password))
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Could not impersonate. Wrong username / password");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UndoImpersonation();
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2; //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.

    private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser;

    private bool ImpersonateValidUser(string username, string domain, string password)
    {
        SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;

        // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
        bool success = LogonUser(username, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);

        if (success)
        {
            using (safeTokenHandle)
            {
                // Use the token handle returned by LogonUser.
                WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
                impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
            }
        }

        return success;
    }

    private void UndoImpersonation()
    {
        // Releasing the context object stops the impersonation
        if (impersonatedUser != null)
        {
            impersonatedUser.Undo();
            impersonatedUser.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeTokenHandle() : base(true)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

And this is the performance monitor graph of two webservers using different versions of the class:

[perfmon http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/5388/captureyog.png](http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/5388/captureyog.png)

When we disable the class, and use global impersonation via web.config, those lines are completely flat.

---

**Update**

I have made a test-application that successfully reproduce the problem. It can be downloaded here:

http://rapidshare.com/files/447325211/ImpersonationTest.zip

The result over 18 hours looks like this:

[testapp http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2055/impersonationtest.png](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2055/impersonationtest.png)

Comment: I've had a look over your code and the implementation of SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid (via Reflector). I'm sure I've probably missed something but I'm not clear where CloseHandle or ReleaseHandle are being called from. Are you expecting this to be called by the inherited Dispose method on SafeTokenHandle?

Comment: I have no idea how it works, i just assume it does, since it's copied from microsoft's site in the link above. I've added a few lines of debugging, and it does get called after the impersonation is done, but that's all i know.

Comment: Given what you say and that the other samples explicitly close the handle then it doesn't appear to be the problem. Have you got an MSDN subscription? If so you could use a Microsoft support incident to get some additional help.

Comment: Yes, we have MSDN subscription, but since i seem to be unable to reproduce the problem locally, i don't think that will help.

Comment: Nevermind that, i updated my question with info on how to reproduce the leak.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue in a web service. How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell. At the very least, `WindowsIdentity` itself is also an `IDisposable`, and the `newId` variable is never disposed of. Also, I would check if all uses of the `Impersonator` class are properly disposed of.

Comment: All uses of the class is made within using-statements, so that should be safe. Good call with the newId-variable though, i'll fix that and send it for test tomorrow.

Comment: Same result with that update. I also made a test-application in our dev-environment, but i can't seem to replicate the leak there. After 1 million impersonations, pool paged bytes remain the same, so i don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: I'm at a loss too. Without additional info (and given the scenario, most likely: without the complete application), it's impossible to tell. I had little hope that disposing the WindowsIdentity might do the trick, but alas.

Comment: I have now managed to reproduce the leak, and the complete application is now found in my question.

Comment: After i changed my test-application to better replicate the behaviour of the production environment (create & delete a file on a network share during impersonation),

Comment: Does the application mimic the actual behaviour of the asp.net application (i.e.: Millions of impersonations and file writes)? When I run the application, the Pool Paged Bytes goes up, regardless if I use impersonation or not. If this is close to the real thing, it may just be that the runtime doesn't get enough time to release resources, and pressure just keeps building up. By simply adding a Thread.Sleep(50) inside the threadproc, the PPB delta stays around zero, and even goes negative.